# Algorithm to choose number of random numbers from list in python?

Tags: python

I am looking for an efficient way (pseudocode will do) to choose a given number of values randomly from the list preferably "Pythonic way". Values have to come from unique indexes of the list

So for example:

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,24]

def choose(number_of_values, list):
    # method

return_val = choose(3, list)
# return_val = [2, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Most pythonic way ever `random.sample(list, 4)` P.s DONT name your variables as `list` as they shadow the builtin

Comment: Take a look at this: [https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its what that [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) is for.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample([0,1,2,3,4,5,24],3)
[2, 24, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop and append the random choices to a list, then return. Also, don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in.

```
import random

def choose(number_of_values, lst):
    _temp = []
    for i in range(number_of_values):
        _temp.append(random.choice(lst))
    return _temp
```